# Convert String to Integer/Float in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, int

```
data GroceryItem = CartItem ItemName Price Quantity | StockItem ItemName Price Quantity

makeGroceryItem :: String -> Float -> Int -> GroceryItem
makeGroceryItem name price quantity = CartItem name price quantity

I want to create a `GroceryItem` when using a `String` or `[String]`

createGroceryItem :: [String] -> GroceryItem
createGroceryItem (a:b:c) = makeGroceryItem a b c
```

The input will be in the format `["Apple","15.00","5"]` which I broke up using Haskell's `words` function.

I get the following error which I think is because `makeGroceryItem` accepts a `Float` and an `Int`.

```
*Type error in application
*** Expression     : makeGroceryItem a read b read c
*** Term           : makeGroceryItem
*** Type           : String -> Float -> Int -> GroceryItem
*** Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d -> e -> f*
```

But how do I make `b` and `c` of type `Float` and `Int`, respectively?

Comment: you have an interesting project. what is it for?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`read` can parse a string into float and int:

```
Prelude> :set +t
Prelude> read "123.456" :: Float
123.456
it :: Float
Prelude> read "123456" :: Int
123456
it :: Int
```

But the problem (1) is in your pattern:

```
createGroceryItem (a:b:c) = ...
```

Here `:` is a (right-associative) binary operator which prepends an element to a list. The RHS of an element must be a list. Therefore, given the expression `a:b:c`, Haskell will infer the following types:

```
a :: String
b :: String
c :: [String]
```

i.e. `c` will be thought as a list of strings. Obviously it can't be `read` or passed into any functions expecting a String.

Instead you should use

```
createGroceryItem [a, b, c] = ...
```

if the list must have exactly 3 items, or

```
createGroceryItem (a:b:c:xs) = ...
```

if ≥3 items is acceptable.

Also (2), the expression

```
makeGroceryItem a read b read c
```

will be interpreted as `makeGroceryItem` taking 5 arguments, 2 of which are the `read` function. You need to use parenthesis:

```
makeGroceryItem a (read b) (read c)
```

Comment: @KennyTM: `read "123.456" :: Float` . What does this syntax mean? What is `::` here? Is `read` a function?

Comment: @Nawaz: Yes `read` is a function. The `f :: T` expression forces `f` to have type `T`.

Comment: @KennyTM: So the syntax `read "123.456" ::Float` is roughly equivalent to `sscanf("123.456", "%f", &fnum);` in C, right?

Comment: @Nawaz: Only for the `read` function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926826/what-does-mean-or-stand-for-in-haskell for detail.

Comment: Internally how does Read actually work? Does it break up the string as a list of Char. Then does it have a dictionary from char to int, and the compare the list of char to to the dictionary in order to get the corresponding int?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: It reads all digits ('0'–'9'), and the convert it to decimal (using 1234 = 123×10 + 4 like all other languages). The actual implementation is quite complicated as it is also generic to support e.g. reading a hex number or reading to a list of integers. See https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Read.html and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Text-Read-Lex.html#numberToInteger if you are interested.

Answer (score 81):

Even though this question already has an answer, I strongly suggest using `reads` for string conversion, because it's much safer, as it does not fail with an unrecoverable exception.

```
reads :: (Read a) => String -> [(a, String)]

Prelude> reads "5" :: [(Double, String)]
[(5.0,"")]
Prelude> reads "5ds" :: [(Double, String)]
[(5.0,"ds")]
Prelude> reads "dffd" :: [(Double, String)]
[]
```

On success, `reads` returns a list with exactly one element: A tuple consisting of the converted value and maybe unconvertable extra characters. On failure, `reads` returns an empty list.

It's easy to pattern-match on success and failure, and it will not blow up in your face!

Comment: Great suggestion! What's your preferred way of extracting the resulting item from the list returned from reads? Two `fst` calls?

Comment: Since base-4.6, there is [`readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) in `Text.Read`, which is more convenient than using `reads` in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Two things:

```
createGroceryItem [a, b, c] = makeGroceryItem a (parse b) (parse c)
-- pattern match error if not exactly 3 items in list
```

or alternatively

```
createGroceryItem (a : b : c : _) = makeGroceryItem a (parse b) (parse c)
-- pattern match error if fewer than 3 items in list, ignore excess items
```

because `:` is not the same as `++`.

Meanwhile on the right hand side --- the side that's giving you the error message you see --- you have to group expressions using brackets. Otherwise `parse` is interpreted as being a value you want to pass to `makeGroceryItem`, so the compiler complains when you try to pass 5 arguments to a function that only takes 3 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
filterNumberFromString :: String -> String
filterNumberFromString s =
    let allowedString = ['0'..'9'] ++ ['.', ',']
        toPoint n
            | n == ',' = '.'
            | otherwise = n

        f = filter (`elem` allowedString) s
        d = map toPoint f
    in d


convertStringToFloat :: String -> Float
convertStringToFloat s =
    let betterString = filterNumberFromString s
        asFloat = read betterString :: Float
    in asFloat

print (convertStringToFloat "15,00" + 1)
```

-> prints 16.0

Thats how I solved this task in my project.

Answer (score 0):

`readMaybe` can be used for this. It is also a **total** function as opposed to `read` (which could throw an exception).

```
Prelude> import Text.Read
Prelude Text.Read> readMaybe ("1.5") :: Maybe Float
Just 1.5
```