# What does :: (double colon) stand for?

Tags: function, haskell, syntax, types

I see and use the `::` symbols *everywhere* but still don't know what the `::` symbol means when programming in Haskell, e.g.

```
run :: Int -> Int -> Int
--  ??
```

What does `::` (double colon) stand for in Haskell?

Comment: It means *has type*, so run has type Int -> Int -> Int. How comes you think you can read Haskell programs without even knowing basic language concepts, symbols and notions? Sometimes it *is* a good idea to read a language reference, and Haskell has a really good one.

Comment: Thanks @Ingo where could I find that reference?

Comment: Your starting point is always haskell.org. The Haskell 2010 Report is here: http://haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf

Comment: http://learnyouahaskell.com/ - excellent book (and entertaining too)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can google for `haskell "double colon"` or similar things; it's unfortunately a bit hard to google for syntax, but in this case you can name it.

In Haskell, your programs will often run fine without it (though you will want to use it to hone the specification of any functions you define, and it is good practice).

The idea is that you can insert a `:: ...` anywhere (even in the middle of an expression) to say "by the way Mr. Compiler, this expression should be of type `...`". The compiler will then throw an error if it can be proved this may not be the case.

I think you can also use it to "cast" functions to the versions you want; e.g. if a function is "polymorphic" (has a general type signature) and you actually want, say an `Integer`, then you could do `:: Integer` on the resulting value perhaps; I'm a bit rusty though.

Comment: You also have more complicated cases of polymorphism, where you want to describe not a specific type, the kind of a type; specifying type works even with ordinary polymorphism.

Comment: That is exactly the search term that landed me here…

Comment: Where does this notation come from? Is it based in mathematics?

Comment: Does this (::) exist as an actual operator in the language? Because when I use GHC, I can't do `:t (::)` or `:k (::)`. Furthermore it seems useful for Data.Typeable, where you can try casting one type to another.

Answer (score 22):

You should read:

```
foo :: a
```

as "the name `foo` refers to a value of type `a`". When you write:

```
run :: a -> b
```

this means:

1. You are declaring the name `run`.
2. This name will refer to a value that have type `a -> b`,

The type `a -> b` is the type of a function which takes a value of type `a` and returns another value of type `b`.

You must really learn about types to understand Haskell. The type system is one of the most crucial feature of Haskell, and it's what makes the language so expressive.

Comment: So `::` is a typedef?

Answer (score 8):

When you have a big scary-looking typechecking error, you can (temporarily) wrap parts of your code in `(myexpression :: MyType)` to explicitly state to the compiler which type you're expecting `myexpression` to have. This will often help the compiler give you better error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Many years later, I ran across this and thought I would point out that there is a subtlety here.  `::` does indicate a type of something.  But it is also used in the description of the `kind` of something:

```
ghci> :type []
[] :: [a]

ghci> :kind []
[] :: * -> *
```

Type and kind are related but different things.

I noticed this from the following in Hackage:

```
class Applicative m => Monad (m :: Type -> Type) where
   ...
```

and the `Type -> Type` is a long form of `* -> *`.

I think the way to read the above is "For some type 'm', where m has kind `* -> *`, `Monad m` extends `Applicative m` and requires the implementation of ..."

Answer (score -1):

directory of file
or that outcast into a specific value cast
key that outcast to a specific value

key:value    = simple
key::value   = casting value there key:value pair  inside the value

key:value(key:value) casting out value

Comment: I don't fully understand what you wrote, but even the parts I do understand seem to point at pattern matching, which is not a correct answer in case.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).