# What is double colon (::) in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

The `::` in `read "7" :: Int`, what does it mean? `:info (::)` in GHCi gives me `"parse error on input ‘::’"`. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly duplicate with [What does :: (double colon) stand for in Haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926826/what-does-double-colon-stand-for-in-haskell), that one is about :: in type signature, this one is about :: in expression.

Comment: Actually, your question is "why do I need to use `::` in with `read`?", isn't it?

Comment: @Zeta I kind of know that why do I need it, because `read "7"` can have different meanings (7 the int or 7 the double), just want a formal definition of ::, is it a operator? is it a hint to compiler? something like that.

Comment: See chapter 3 of the Haskell2010 report. It's an *expression type signature*. It's not an operator, it's a language construct.