# What does the 22::Int mean here?

Tags: haskell

What does the `22 :: Int` mean here?

```
rotor3=("BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO",22::Int)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does :: (double colon) stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926826/what-does-double-colon-stand-for)

Answer (score 5):

`22 :: Int` expresses the same value as `22` by itself, but with additional information to the compiler to treat it specifically as type `Int`.

Now you may wonder, doesn't `22` have type `Int` *anyway*? It does in many other programming languages, but in Haskell it has out of the box a more general type `Num a => a`, meaning it can have any numerical type, depending on what the context demands. This is necessary because Haskell doesn't have automatic *conversion* of types. For example, if you write `sin 22`, the literal `22` will be treated as having the type `Double`, in `['a'..'z']!!22` it'll be treated as having the type `Int`, and in `22^9` it'll be treated as having the type `Integer`.

```
ghci> sin 22
-8.851309290403876e-3
ghci> ['a'..'z']!!22
'w'
ghci> 22^100
174690015040882455988354400790170000897162886859579152352704471899874163427116241050767381769631464055938734482112142486751362076901376
```

Manually specifying the type to `Int`, or some other concrete type, prevents this automatic type selection. In the above examples this would cause some problems:

```
ghci> ['a'..'z']!!(22::Float)

<interactive>:8:14: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Float’
    • In the second argument of ‘(!!)’, namely ‘(22 :: Float)’
      In the expression: ['a' .. 'z'] !! (22 :: Float)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = ['a' .. 'z'] !! (22 :: Float)

ghci> sin (22::Int)

<interactive>:5:1: error:
    • No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘sin’
    • In the expression: sin (22 :: Int)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = sin (22 :: Int)

ghci> (22::Int)^100   -- overflow
0
```

But sometimes it is necessary to give the compiler some concrete information about what types you want, since it can otherwise be ambiguous. A typical example if when you read values from a string: the following doesn't work

```
ghci> read "22"
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

What's happening here is that absent any info *as which type* you want to read the string, the compiler (which isn't aware that the string contains at runtime a number) picks the most simple type it could be, namely `()`. But there's only one value that parses for that type:

```
ghci> read "()"
()
```

To actually parse a number, you need to explicitly say its type:

```
Prelude> read "22" :: Int
22
Prelude> read "22" :: Double
22.0
```

Note that this is *not* necessary if the type can be inferred from the context:

```
ghci> ['a'..'z'] !! read "22"
'w'
```

(BTW using `read` is widely considered a bad idea, because of the potential for runtime errors; better use [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe).)

Answer (score 2):

`22` is a constant that can be of *any* numeric type: `Int,Integer,Float,Double,....` and many others.

By annotating it with a type as in `22::Int`, we require the second component of the pair `rotor3` to have type `Int`.

Another option (which I personally prefer) is to annotate `rotor3` directly.

```
rotor3 :: (String, Int)
rotor3 = ("BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO", 22)
```

In this case the `22` is automatically inferred to be an `Int` constant.