# Have a list of strings but need a list of Integers

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list with a string inside it and I need to have that deconstructed Char by Char and put into a list as Integer instead but I'm stymied by the types

What i have is a txt file that i read into monad:

```
getTxt = do
  y <- readFile "foo.txt"
  return y
```

`foo` only contains this:

```
"1234567890\n"
```

then I thought I was close with sequence but that gets me this list:

```
["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"] :: [[Char]]
```

but I need `[Integer]`. `ord` will take `Char -> Int` but how do I read that `[Char] -> [Int]` ? And after all these trial and only error, don't I need to filter out that last new line in the end?

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question will probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468410/convert-string-to-integer-float-in-haskell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `ord`, the types match, but it's not what you want because `ord` gives you 
the ascii value, not the numeric value: `ord 5` is `53`, not `5`. You could subtract 
48 to get the digit, then roll the digits up into a single number, but it would be 
easier to use a library function. The most straightforward choice is `read`:

```
getInt :: IO Integer
getInt = do
    y <- readFile "foo.txt"
    return (read (takeWhile (/='\n') y))
```

As in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468410/convert-string-to-integer-float-in-haskell), 
the best solution here is to use `reads`.

`reads` finds a list of possible matches, 
as pairs of `(match,remainingstring)`, 
which works well for you because it will automatically leave the newline in the remaining string,

`*Main> reads "31324542\n" :: [(Integer,String)]`
`[(31324542,"\n")]`

Let's use that:

```
findInt :: String -> Maybe Integer
findInt xs = case reads xs of              -- have a look at reads xs
    ((anint,rest):anyothers) -> Just anint -- if there's an int at the front of the list, just return it
    _ -> Nothing                           -- otherwise return nothing
```

`Maybe`'s a handy data type that lets you have failure without crashing the program or doing exception handling.
`Just 5` means you got output and it's `5`. `Nothing` means there was a problem, no output.

```
addTen :: FilePath -> IO ()
addTen filename = do
    y <- readFile filename
    case findInt y of 
       Just i -> putStrLn ("Added 10, got "++show (i+10))
       Nothing -> putStrLn ("Didn't find any integer at the beginning of " ++ filename)
```

Which gives you:

`*Main> addTen "foo.txt"`
`Added 10, got 1234567890`

---

If you just want the integers the characters represent, you can put `import Data.Char` at the top of your file and do

```
ordzero = ord '0'   -- handy constant, 48, to unshift the ascii code to a digit.

getInts :: FilePath -> IO [Int]          -- ord gives the smaller Int, not Integer
getInts filename = do
    y <- readFile filename
    return [ord achar - ordzero | achar <- takeWhile isDigit y]
```

This takes the characters of the string `y` for as long as they're digits, 
then finds their `ord`, subtracting `ord '0'` (which is 48) to turn `'4'` into `4` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Read documentation of `map` and `filter`. It it very important.
 In your case

```
integersFromFile :: String -> IO [Int]
integersFromFile filename = map digitToInt <$> readFile filename
```

Comment: You probably meant `integersFromFile filename = map ord <$> readFile filename` since the code doesn't typecheck.

Comment: Yeah. You right. And also, I did't double checked, that OP wants digitToInt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, but my version of what I think illusionoflife is suggesting is a list comprehension...

```
do cs <- readFile "foo.txt"
   return [ord c | c <- cs, c /= '\n']
```

This is a bit of a cheat - it assumes the file will only contain digits and that end-of-line, and just strips out any end-of-line characters wherever they occur.

Explanation - this is a [list comprehension](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension). The `c <- cs` basically assigns `c` each character in turn. The `c /= '\n'` filters out cases with the line-end (wherever it occurs - it doesn't have to be at the end). The `ord c` gives the values to include in the final list.

This could be expressed using `filter` and `map`, but once you get used to it, a list comprehension is much more convenient.

An improved version might use `isDigit` (from [Data.Char](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Char.html)) to check characters. There also [Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Maybe.html) a way to track whether there are invalid characters in the list, so you can either check for and report those markers later or filter them out.

Comment: Oops - yes, sorry, I wasn't thinking and I haven't been using Haskell for a while. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a function that has this type:

```
charsToInts :: [Char] -> [Int]
```

We can solve this by decomposing the problem into smaller problems.  First, we need a function that converts a single `Char` to a `String`:

```
charToString :: Char -> String
charToString c = [c]
```

... then we need a function that converts a `String` to an `Int`:

```
stringToInt :: String -> Int
stringToInt = read
```

... then we compose those two functions to get a function that converts `Char`s to `Int`s:

```
charToInt :: Char -> Int
charToInt = stringToInt . charToString
```

Now, we can lift that function to process an entire list of `Char`s by using `map`:

```
charsToInts :: [Char] -> [Int]
charsToInts = map charToInt
```

... and we're done!

I took a very verbose path just for demonstrative purposes.  In my own code I would typically inline all these definitions like so:

```
charsToInts :: [Char] -> [Int]
charsToInts = map (read . singleton)
  where singleton x = [x]
```

To use `stringsToInts` in your code, you would just write:

```
getTxt :: IO [Int]
getTxt = fmap charsToInts $ readFile "foo.txt"
```

That `fmap` applies `charsToInts` to the result of `readFile`, and the above code is equivalent to:

```
getTxt = do
    chars <- readFile "foo.txt"
    return $ charsToInts chars
```

[outside comment:

You can reduce it even further, with a list comprehension:

```
getTxt :: IO [Int]
getTxt = do
    chars <- readFile "foo.txt"
    return [read [d] | d <- chars]
```

Notice that while type annotations for top-level functions are generally a good idea, in this case it is mandatory (unless you put an annotation into the function body).  That is because "read" otherwise doesn't know what type you want.
]