# Reverse a String containing Numbers

Tags: string, sorting, haskell, integer, numbers

I want to reverse an Integer.

My current idea is to convert the Integer to a string using the `show` function and then recursively sort the string.

I have the following code:

```
reverseInt :: Integer -> String
reverseInt num = show (num)
reverseInt [] = []
reverseInt (x:xs) = (reverseInt xs) ++ [x]
```

Now the problem is that the function doesn't use the string I just created by using the `show` function, it expects an integer.

Comment: Convert the resulting string back into an integer.

Comment: How do I do it in my code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667478/haskell-string-int-type-conversion

Comment: There's no definition of `reverseInt1` in the code you posted. Is this really all the relevant code? If it's not, post the rest; it would also help if you posted the error message you're getting.

Comment: mistyped, it should be just reverseInt

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like homework, so I'll talk about what the problem is, but I won't give code that reverses an integer.

The type error is really a red herring here. In Haskell, a pattern which is just an identifier (like `num`) will match anything. If a pattern matches, later patterns aren't considered at all. So what you wrote is almost the same as writing

```hs
reverseInt :: Integer -> String
reverseInt num = show num
```

The compiler got confused because, even though the last two lines are dead code, it wants them to have the correct type anyway. They don't have the correct type, because the pattern `[]` can only match lists, never an `Integer`. So it errors out early: it never got far enough in the compilation process to tell you that you wrote dead code. (Actually, if you comment out the type signature, it'll actually compile your code, infer the type `String -> String` for `reverseInt`, and warn you about overlapping patterns; it's just a lucky coincidence that it manages to find types for everything, though.)

I think what you want to write is really three functions:

```hs
intToString :: Integer -> String -- turns the Integer into a String
reverseString :: String -> String -- reverses the String
stringToInt :: String -> Integer -- turns the String back into an Integer
```

Then, you can just compose them to complete your assignment. What you have is very, very close to being the first *two* of these functions.