# Get rid of double quotes from JSON when printing

Tags: haskell

When I do pattern matching this way:

```
case HashMap.lookup "abc" jsn of
  Just (Number n) -> putStrLn $ show n
```

it gets printed as 123.45 (without double quotes) which is what I want. When I do it this way:

```
case HashMap.lookup "abc" jsn of
  Just (String val) -> print val
```

it prints it as "123.45" (with double quotes). In the second case I have to do pattern matching against String because **it is** a String value in JSON. But I don't want it to be printed with double quotes. How do I get rid of them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468410/convert-string-to-integer-float-in-haskell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
case HashMap.lookup "abc" jsn of
  Just (String val) -> putStrLn val
```

`print` is just `putStrLn . show`, and when you `show` a string, it gets quotes. `show` converts things to strings, so you can just pass your string directly to `putStrLn`.