# Power given in a String to Integer

Tags: haskell

We know [how to convert a String to an Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468410/convert-string-to-integer-float-in-haskell) for a String such as `"50"`. Assume the String is `"2^3"`, how to get `8` from it ? Is there something which works when it is not known in advance that the operation is a power, something which would also work for `"2+3"`, etc ?

Comment: That sounds like a parser. What exactly do you mean by "*etc*", i.e. what's the syntax you're trying to parse?

Comment: @melpomene An elementary expression whose result is an integer, such as a+b, a*b, a^b, a+b+c.

Comment: You are looking for this: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins-1.5.5.0/docs/System-Eval-Haskell.html

Comment: @Sibi Looks good! I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no expression evaluator available in the
basic Haskell libraries.

Will this work for you?

```
import System.Process

eval :: String -> IO Integer
eval expr = do
  r <- readProcess "ghc" ["-e", expr] ""
  return (read r)

main = eval "2^3" >>= print
```

But it runs in the IO monad and it's not very robust.

Comment: Is it better than https://hackage.haskell.org/package/plugins-1.5.5.0/docs/System-Eval-Haskell.html ?

Comment: It's simpler, doesn't require installation of any extra libraries, but it's not as capable. It all depends on your requirements.

Answer (score -2):

Hum, you could try to use [QuasiQuotes](https://wiki.haskell.org/Quasiquotation) for this:

```
ghci> :set -XQuasiQuotes
ghci> :set -XTemplateHaskell
ghci> let a = [|1 + 1|]
ghci> $a
2
ghci>
```

Comment: Nice, but the input is not given as a String.

Comment: You can do the same without TH: `let a = 1 + 1`