# How can I make `elem` check my input between a list of 1-50 rather than 1-9? It rejects anything more than single digits

Tags: haskell

```
    discLocation :: Grid -> IO Int

    discLocation grid = do
  
    putStrLn "Enter number from the grid "
 
    value <- getLine
  
    if value `elem` [1..50] && validSlot grid (read [value])
 
    then return  $ (read [value])
  
    else discLocation grid
```

How can I make it so that the list is [1..50] without getting a parse error? Now I get the parse error on the '[value]' part as it says expected type Char but actual type is String.

Comment: Anything that's more than a single digit is no longer a `Char` -- it's 2 or more `Char`s.  Perhaps you want to use `getLine`?  You can also use [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) to help check if it's in bounds rather than making a list of all the `String`s from 1-50.

Comment: What do you actually want?  Do you want a number or a string?

Comment: You want to write `[1..50]` rather than  `['1'..'50']`. Integers not Chars. Surrounding single quotes imply the Char type.

Comment: @DDub I have updated my code and I am still getting errors as explained above :/

Comment: @jpmarinier I have tried that but I am still getting errors as indicated above on my edited code :/

Comment: @AjwadAli The type of `getLine` is `IO String` ; as you initialize `value` using `value <- getLine` that makes your  `value` an object of type `String`. Hence `value` cannot be an element in a list of Int values, just because it is a String not an Int, and the compiler can see that.  See here for example: [SO-q2468410](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468410/convert-string-to-integer-float-in-haskell)

Comment: The post that @jpmarinier pointed to is a good one.  My advice is to try to use `readMaybe` -- specifically, to use it _before_ you check if the value is between 1 and 50.

Answer (score 0):

```
discLocation :: Int -> IO Int

discLocation grid = do
  putStrLn "Enter number from the grid "
  value <- getLine
  if read value `elem` [1..50] && validSlot grid (read value)
    then return  $ read value
    else discLocation grid

validSlot :: Int -> Int -> Bool
validSlot _ _ = True
```

The above will load in ghci and it works as expected. It is important that validSlot knows that its second argument is an Int - so that (read value) can infer that it should return an int. I find the following a bit easier to read

```
discLocation grid = do
  putStrLn "Enter number from the grid "
  value <- readLn
  if value `elem` [1..50] && validSlot grid value
    then return value
    else discLocation grid
```

Here since you are returning value and discLocation is of type Grid -> IO Int, readLn knows that it should read an Int.